# How do I Disable Screen blanking on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running raspbian and I am using this as a display device for a tv in a retail centre.

I run chromium on startup with this line in .profile

```
xinit /usr/bin/chromium --kiosk --incognito www.mysite.com
```

however non of the solutions to disable blanking seem to work (although they do work if I am in the raspbian gui).

It is quite important (as you can imagine) that the display screen does not go blank......

Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

KBD is what seems to causes the screen-blanking.
You can disable KBD's screen blanking via it's configuration file, /etc/kbd/config.
Open this with a text editor such as vi, nano, or leafpad.
Note that this requires administrative rights.
Then change the line

```
BLANK_TIME=30
```

to

```
BLANK_TIME=0
```

In order for these settings to take effect, restart/reboot your RPi, or restart KBD with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/kbd restart
```

If you are still getting blanking after that, then changing LightDM's config might fix it.
Edit LightDM's configuration file (/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf, requires root), and add the following line after the line "[SeatDefaults]"

```
xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms
```

Note that i have only tested the KBD method!
Sources:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=18181
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=18200&p=180271#p180271

Answer (score 0):

What I did to disable screen blanking on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian.

Created a file on `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`:

```
# /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98x11-screen_blank
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
```

Be sure you have `xset` installed. The latest Raspbian already have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the blank screen at every startup, just type:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and in the [SeatDefaults] section add or uncomment this line:

```
xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms
```

Then:

```
ctrl + x
y
press enter
reboot
```

wait for 20 min and it should still be on. This is if you are Running Raspbian-jessie with Pixel.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put these lines [1]

```
@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
```

into the file [2]

```
~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

[1] https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57552

[2] https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Autostart_Programs